# How to unzip a blob programmatically using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am following the [quickstart tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python) on using the python azure sdk to copy a blob from one container to the next. This works in transferring the blob, but I'd like the blob in the receiving/sink container to be unzipped (basically what [this tutorial on ADF is performing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEtpvdnULZ8), except I want to use the SDK, not the UI).

The block of code from the tutorial that performs the copy activity is as follows

```py
# here ds_name_* variables refers to Azure datasets for source and sink, respectively
    act_name = 'copyBlobtoBlob'
    blob_source = BlobSource()
    blob_sink = BlobSink()
    dsin_ref = DatasetReference(reference_name=ds_name_in, type='DatasetReference')
    dsout_ref = DatasetReference(reference_name=ds_name_out, type='DatasetReference')
    copy_activity = CopyActivity(name=act_name, inputs=[dsin_ref], outputs=[dsout_ref], source=blob_source, sink=blob_sink)
        # make pipeline w/ copy activity
    p_name = 'copyPipeline'
    params_for_pipeline = {}
    p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[copy_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
    p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)

    #create pipeline run
    run_response = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(rg_name, df_name, p_name, parameters={})
```

The SDK documentation for the [`CopyActivity` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.copyactivity?view=azure-python) mentions an `additional_properties` parameter that may be relevant, but does not exemplify possible values.  There is also a [`ZipDeflateReadSettings` class that may be relevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.zipdeflatereadsettings?view=azure-python), but I cannot find a use case for it anywhere online or in the docs.

Edit:

The part of my script, pasted below, where I create a dataset may also be salient. Again the [sdk doc for the `DatasetResource` class doesn't indicate any compression/decompression parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.datasetresource?view=azure-python).

```py
    ds_name_out = 'ds_out'
    ds_ls_out = LinkedServiceReference(reference_name=ls_name_out, type='LinkedServiceReference')
    blob_path_out = 'container_name/folder_name' # container name
    ds_azure_blob_out = DatasetResource(properties=AzureBlobDataset(
        linked_service_name=ds_ls_out, folder_path=blob_path_out))
    ds = adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(
        rg_name, df_name, ds_name_out, ds_azure_blob_out)
```

Comment: I don't know about the Python SDK, but your idea that the Dataset may be salient sounds correct. A binary Dataset may have a compression defined: if it does, then that Dataset as a Source will Unzip its contents as part of the Copy operation. Likewise, if the Dataset is the Sink, it will zip the contents in flight.

Answer (score 0):

The object to parametrize with compression information in this case was `AzureBlobDataset`.  By passing a `compression` argument I was able to unzip the zip file in the target container:

```py
ds_azure_blob_in = DatasetResource(properties=AzureBlobDataset(
        linked_service_name=ds_ls_in, folder_path=blob_path, file_name=blob_filename, compression=DatasetCompression(type='ZipDeflate')))
```

I think confusion arose from the abuse of abstraction in the Azure SDK here. I may be wrong, but something tells me that nesting three class instances in the above solution is not a pretty design pattern for a seemingly trivial task.